# Is there a way to draw only certain lines in wireframe of Plane Mesh in Three.js?

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, webgl, glsl

I want to be able to show or hide the diagonal lines in the wireframe of my PlaneGeometry mesh, as well as being able to show or hide vertical or horizontal lines. Is there a way to do this and retain the triangles in my mesh? I already have 'wireframe: true' set on the material and can color it. I've been able to do this in the past with OpenGL, is it possible with Three.js?

Comment: One option is to use a `THREE.Line` to manually draw the wireframe you want. You can start with your existing geometry and just put the vertices into a path in the appropriate order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, or modify to your liking, `src/extras/helpers/GridHelper.js`.

There is also `src/extras/helpers/WireframeHelper.js`.

See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_helpers.html

EDIT: `THREE.EdgesHelper` has been added to the library. It will not render the diagonal lines of flat faces.

three.js. r.65

Comment: I dont understand how this helps. I have a mesh already constructed that has a GLSL vertex shader displacing the vertices. When I add the following code to my scene all it does is generate another Wireframe Mesh. How do change the wireframe of an existing mesh to only display vertical lines?  ' var helper = new THREE.WireframeHelper( mesh );
     helper.material.depthTest = false;
     helper.material.opacity = 1.0;
     helper.material.transparent = true;
     scene.add( helper );'

Comment: I have a ShaderMaterial that is set for 'wireframe: true', where can I augment the wireframe of this material that is applied to a mesh?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you will have to modify one of the helpers to render only the face edges you want to see. There are no other options in three.js that will achieve the effect you desire.

Comment: Your "accept" rate is zero. Please remember to accept answers by clicking on the check mark next to the answer. Do this for others who have answered your questions, too.

Comment: This answer did not lead me to a solution for my problem.